# WCF and Client accessing error, local runs fine, on uploading gives 404

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, proxy, wcf-client

I have a RESTful service on a server whose url say is **www.webserve.com**
i have a proxy client on my local machine to hit and get the details from this service.. the client has a page name **default.aspx** which post and hit the **www.webserve.com** and get the data.

it works fine but as soon as i upload this client on the same server(IIS) with a name say **www.proxyclient.com** and open it with my browser the **default.aspx** works fine but as soon as i post the data and hit the service through it it gives mt a **404 error**..

I dont know whats wrong with it.. may be this is the static vs dynamic IP mess or something like that.. 
can u please help me out. i need to get this done on urgent basis

Thnx guys

Alright got the solution. my proxyclient was using a handler to handle a custom extension. I mapped that extension to IIS with aspnet dll and it worked.. thnx guys for ur support :)

Comment: paste here your disco file detail

Comment: where do you get the 404 - in the web page or the REST service?

Comment: In client application where mapped your wcf is known as DISCO the discovery of uri

Comment: use something like Fidler to see if the client access the desired location (proxyclient.com) and not webserve.com

Comment: @RichardBlewett Restservice.. page runs fine..

Comment: So if I can paraphrase your question to make sure I understand it: "if I change the domain name the REST service always returns a 404". Is the REST service and the web app on the same site/virtual directory or separate ones?

Comment: no restservice is on another domain name(www.webserve.com). and client has virual directory which has this proxyclient to access the restservice(www.proxyclient.com/proxyAPIModule).
so the job of this proxyAPImodule which is a virtual directory is to get the request from the client and hit the service and return back the response... localmachine runs fine but uploading on server gives 404 while hitting service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I needed to register .svc to my IIS ISAPI with .net framework dll

then it worked fine :)